# how to write before update trigger?

Tags: sqlite, triggers

I have two tables namely table1 and table2.

**When table1 is updated, I want to insert the row being updated to table2 so that table2 serves as a log.**

table1 has column1,column2,column3,column4....column10

table2 has column1,column2,column3,column4

So while inserting into table2, I just want column1,column2,column3,column4 from table1.

Answer (score 0):

This will be simple if you just want to add the record updated from `table1` to `table2` and you can use after update

```
delimiter //
create trigger update_table1 after update on table1
for each row 
begin
 insert into table2 
 (column1,column2,column3,column4)
 values
 (old.column1,old.column2,old.column3,old.column4);
end; //
delimiter;
```

Comment: No this wont help. The reason is I want to log the previous values in table1, so that I wont lose them

Comment: Just change `new` to `old` to get the old values I have updated the answer.

Comment: so old is the system defined thing? or are you explaining something else?

Comment: yes old and new are system defined keyword for triggers they are used to get the column value before the operation and after the operation http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html